# Chrome Sources Displaying Javascript in Chinese

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript was working properly and then all of the sudden it wasn't. Chrome give me the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error on line 1 of my JS file called para2.js. I removed script from the file except for the following and I still get the error:

```
$( window ).ready(function() {
});
```

My jQuery file is included in the head of my document:

```
<script src="../shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/para2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I look at my js file in Chrome developer tools on the Sources tab, it displays the script in Chinese:

```
兪敵祲搨捯浵湥⥴爮慥祤昨湵瑣潩⡮笩⥽
```

When I view the source of the js file, it looks fine. I have read similar posts that say copy and pasting from JSFiddle can include some hidden characters that may cause it, but I have started from scratch writing this file from a blank text file and copy and pasting nothing. It is strange that it was working and now it is not. Did my server get hacked or something? And help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably because the encoding of your para2.js file is not correct. Try use another text editor and type in again. You can start with a very simple javascript file.

Comment: And it does not seem to be related to jQuery itself. Any javascript code I insert responds the same way. I tried a simple alert and console.log and both give me the same error and strange Chinese.

Comment: I am using Coda 2.5.7. I created a new file and added an alert script with TextEdit, uploaded with Coda and still get the same issue.

Comment: It's possible that the invalid character is actually in your HTML file, near where the <script> tag to include para2.js is.  Check that line and the previous line.

Comment: I pulled the code from off my server, rewrote it and ran it in MAMP. It seems to be working now, but I am not sure why. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 14):

You should use the `charset` attribute to indicate which charset you are using.

```
<script src="../shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! must be some characters in the html itself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with jquery-1.5.1.min.js. Chrome kept evaluating it as Chinese (scripts worked fine in IE). I finally solved the problem by re-encoding the .js files using "convert to UTF-8" in Notepad++.  Note, not UTF-8 without BOM, but UTF-8.